# How do I change the value of a textbox with this JQuery?

Tags: jquery, textbox

I have script working that will change the value of my textbox as needed.  I am trying to change it even more.

```
var total = 0; // adds a decimal and 2 zeros
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
 total += isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).val());
}); 

$("#total").val(total.toFixed(2));
```

```
$.fn.digits = function(){ // adds a comma every 3 numbers 
    return this.each(function(){ 
        $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") ); 
    })
}
$("#total").digits();
```

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" style="background-color:#ffffff;">
```

```
<span id="total_text"></span>
```

```
$("#total_text").digits(); // this works to change the span tag
```

.toFixed(2) changes the textbox and the span tag just fine.

When I try to add .digits() nothing happens to the textbox.

Comment: Will you point out the incorrect part?

Comment: `$.fn.digits` uses `$(this).text()`, but you have to use `.val()` for an input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.val()` to read and change the value of a textbox, not `.text()`. So the function needs to check which type of element `$(this)` is.

```
$.fn.digits = function(){ // adds a comma every 3 numbers 
    return this.each(function(){
        var method = $(this).is(":input") ? "val" : "text";
        $(this)[method]( $(this)[method]().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") ); 
    })
}
$("#total").digits();
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!  I only had to remove a period.
$(this)[method]( $(this) //--->.<---\\ [method]().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") );